# Connecting 2 random users from Firebase Realtime Database with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I’m creating an app where I need to match two random users from my Firebase Database. My issue is that I'm not sure how to retrieve the list of users actively searching for a match. Here's how my database structure looks like:

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2kYz.jpg)

I'm looking to read the list of users searching for a match and compare match preferences to randomly match 2 users together.  any suggestions on the syntax I should use to retrieve the list from Firebase Realtime Database to build the random matching logic?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UserModel getRandomUser(UserModel currentUser, List<UserModel> activelySearching) {
  final matchedUsers = activelySearching.where(
    (otherUser) {
      return currentUser.uid != otherUser.uid &&
      currentUser.genderPreference == otherUser.userGender &&
      currentUser.userGender == otherUser.genderPreference &&

      currentUser.maxAgePreference >= otherUser.userAge &&
      currentUser.minAgePreference <= otherUser.userAge &&

      currentUser.userAge <= otherUser.maxAgePreference &&
      currentUser.userAge >= otherUser.minAgePreference &&
    }
  ).toList();

  // import 'dart:math'; to use Random
  final index = Random().nextInt(matchedUsers.length);
  return matchedUsers[index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mohamed.oussous for the tip there! How should I define UserModel? I have tried your suggestion and got an error that UserModel is not a defined class.

Comment: of course you have to define it yourself by parsing the JSON data to a UserModel

Comment: see https://medium.com/flutter-community/converting-json-into-class-objects-in-dart-abcc3cc05478

Comment: this video also helped on parsing the JSON data to a UserModel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXBJZD0fBa4